# SQL for BETWEEN two dates

Tags: php, sql

I have tried researching but can't figure it out.  My SQL table has a column of type "date" which structures the data as YYYY-MM-DD.  How do I perform an SQL query to search between two dates?

If I change start - end to 1 - 999999999 then it displays all my data, so I know my query is working.  I just can't get it to understand my date values.

```html
<?php
$start = '2015-01-01'
$end = '2015-12-31'

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Week BETWEEN $start AND $end)";

?>
```

Comment: Maybe quotes `BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'`

Comment: What datatype is `Week`?

Comment: I see this question a lot. Please read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: It was indeed the lack of quotes around my $start and $end in the SQL query.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Week BETWEEN $start AND $end)";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Week BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
```

and the fields $start and $end should be of the type date

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
 $start = '2015-01-01';
 $end = '2015-12-31';

$query=  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Week 
BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
```

OR

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Week   
>= '$start'   AND  Week <= '$end'";
```